Can the contents of a variable be used for Serilog template property name (not value)?
var slProp = "Application";
var appName = "caTest";
var username = "user01";
Log.Information("{slProp} starting and using credentials of {UserName}", appName, username);

Looking for log entry to have:

message: caTest starting and using credentials of user01
Application = caTest
UserName = user01

As it is now I'm seeing:

message: caTest starting and using credentials of user01
slProp = caTest
UserName = user01

Is there a way to use the value of {slProp} (Application) instead of (slProp)?
Trying to come up with a shared resource that other developers can leverage so all apps are using the same property names.  For example:  ApplicationName, UserName, OrderNumber, ...  So when users are searching for a common property the property will be the same is all applications.

You can use string interpolation to generate the message template; analyzers such as SerilogAnalyzers will complain, but it will work correctly and there won't be a memory leak $$"{{slProp}} starting and using credentials of {UserName}". I would say most people don't go down this road though, and suck up the fact that the property names need to be correctly spelled at all times. Another thing that can help is putting properties like the app name into the context via e.g. va logger = logger.ForContext("Application",appName) etc
